# Why do I get this error message when using gparted in the live cd?

Tags: gparted

So, I have just bought a new laptop. I used a live cd to check the default partitions and I get this error (see screenshot). Why is that? I am slightly worried because my last HD had so many bad sectors that I had to throw it away after a year or so and it was due to bad partitions. [image]

Update: I was wondering if the second image with the error message is something I should worry about too:[image]

I just clicked ignore.

Comment: Right click on it and then click "information" or "more info" (or something like that) to see information about the warning.

Answer (score 1):

I see no error in the screenshot. That Microsoft reserved partition is used by Windows. Probably it is a recovery partition or so. It is hard to say from your screenshot alone. The red symbol in front of it does not signify a problem here. These particular partitions do not have a recognisable filesystem.

Comment: What do you mean by "These particular partitions do not have a recognisable filesystem"? they are fat32,ntfs and one partition is unrecognizable.

Comment: I mean 'these particular partitions' as in partitions like the Microsoft reserved partition.  There are more types of partitions with similar characteristics but that's outside the scope of your question.

Answer (score 1):

As `gparted` already reports, this is a `Microsoft Reserved Partition`.

It is a partition Windows reserves for possible future use.

Wikipedia can tell you a bit more: [Microsoft_Reserved_Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition)